How is the definition of an $n$-tuple implemented in formal treatments of set theory?
In some textbooks on axiomatic set theory, I have seen the following definition of an $n$-tuple:
\begin{align}
() &= \varnothing \\
(v_0) &= v_0 \\
(v_0,v_1) &= \{\{v_0\},\{v_0,v_1\}\} \\
(v_0,v_1,v_2) &= ((v_0,v_1),v_2) \\
(v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3) &= ((v_0,v_1,v_2),v_3) \, , \\
\end{align}
and so on, with $(v_0,\dots,v_n,v_{n+1})=((v_0,\dots,v_n),v_{n+1})$. How would this definition be implemented in formal treatments of $\mathsf{ZFC}$? As far as I can tell, this definition does not correspond to "expansion by definitions", since usually when we work in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ we only expand the language by finitely many predicate symbols and function symbols. It seems then that this definition takes place "within $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself", but I am not clear on the details.

Generally, we can just talk about $I$-tuples which are functions with domain $I$ for any set $I$.

@AsafKaragila: Thanks for your response. I much prefer the definition you propose, and it makes sense to me, but I have seen the definition given in my question in books like Jech's Set Theory (p. 7). Assuming that Jech has not made a mistake in his definition, it seems that there should be some way of actually carrying it out in a formal treatment of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but there are a number of details that are not clear to me.

Another potential issue is that it is not clear to me whether the "$n$" in $(v_0,\dots,v_n,v_{n+1})=((v_0,\dots,v_n),v_{n+1})$ is meant to denote a metatheoretical integer, or an element of $\omega$.

If you use Asaf's definition of $I$-tuples then it's an element of $\omega$. If you use the inductive definition in your post then it's a meta-level natural number.

@NaïmFavier: Okay, thank you. Suppose then that I am writing a proof in ordinary English, and I write something like "for every natural number $n$, if $(v_1,\dots, v_n)$ be a linearly independent family of vectors, then it can be extended to a basis". Since this sentence, when translated into a statement in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, will involve quantification over the natural numbers, isn't it essential that I use the $I$-tuple definition? After all, it's not possible to write a sentence in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that quantifies over the metatheoretical integers.

@Joe Yes, that sounds correct.

Let me use n for metatheoretic integers and $n$ for elements of $\omega$. Taken literally, what you wrote is infinitely many definitions, one for each n, but it can be turned into a single definition, as follows. A $2$-tuple is a Kuratowski pair $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, and an $n+1$-tuple is a set of the form $((a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}),a_n)$ where $(a_0,\dots,a_{n-1})$ is an $n$-tuple. This is a recursive definition. To spell out the details, a set $x$ is an $n$-tuple iff there is a function $f$ with domain $n-1=\{0,1,\dots,n-2\}$ such that (1) $f(0)$ is a $2$-tuple; (2) for each $i<n-2$, $f(i+1)$ is $(f(i),b)$ for some $b$; (3) $f(n-2)=x$. It can then be shown by induction in the metatheory that for each integer n, an n-tuple in your definition is the same as an $n$-tuple.
Clearly it's way simpler to just define an $n$-tuple to be a function of domain $n$. I've always wondered why Jech chooses this rather inconvenient definition (and it has the bug/feature? that an $n$-tuple is also an $m$-tuple for any $2\leq m\leq n$). I guess it has something to do with the Godel operations $G_9$ and $G_{10}$; see definition 13.6.

Thanks, this is exactly the kind of answer that I needed – something that explained how to remove the self-reference in the definition of an $n$-tuple, similar to how the proof of the Recursion Theorem tells us how to remove the self-reference in the definition $(n+1)!=(n+1)n!$. How did you know to define $f$ like this – is this just a special case of the Recursion Theorem in disguise? Sorry if my question isn't clear.

Also, I think your definition of an $n$-tuple in your sentence "To special out the details..." is missing some final clause. I think it should be something like $X$ is an $n$-tuple iff there is a function $f$ with domain $n-1$ such that $f(0)$ is a $2$-tuple, and for each $i<n-2$, $f(i+1)$ is of the form $(f(i),b)$ for some $b$, and $f(n-2)=X$.

@Joe Thanks, fixed. I would say it's more like transfinite recursion than usual recursion. Usual recursion: for any $a\in X$ and $F:X\rightarrow X$ there exists a unique $f:\omega\rightarrow X$ such that $f(0)=a$ and $f(n+1)=F(f(n))$. Transfinite recursion: for any set $a$ and any class function $F:V\rightarrow V$ (which is essentially just a formula) there exists a unique function $f$ with domain $\omega$ such that $f(0)=a$ and $f(n+1)=F(f(n))$. The difference is that for transfinite recursion you need the axiom of replacement at some point.

In either case, the existence of such $f$ is proved using "partial approximation". To phrase my answer using transfinite recursion, fix a set $A$ and consider the class function $F(X)=X\times A={(x,a):x\in X,\ a\in A}$. If we set $f(0)=A$ then $f(n)$ is the set of $n+1$-tuples with entries in $A$.
